# On-premises Question & Answers website engine (Open source/commercial)

Tags: web-development, self-hosted, forum

I'm looking for the open source/commercial engine for Question & Answers website like StackOverflow. Please recommend.

I should have the possibility to customize the engine with my own functionality If I'll need it.

Comment: It must be in PHP? If not, I suggest you remove that tag to remove that limit. It would be also great if you'll list the important features you need. There are plenty of Q&A sites, and each has something different

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have removed the PHP tag

Comment: On premise / online?

Comment: Preferable solution - I should have the possibility to customize the engine with my own functionality If I'll need it.

Comment: Err, possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange clones on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Different site so it is not considered a duplicate from here's point of view :-)

Comment: Notes for your consideration (it would be best if you'll update your question regards those): `*` Is it going to be public (building a community) or for a personal/enterprise? `*` Do you need custom authentication, or just regular signup is fine? `*` How much you want to custom it? To custom a bit or to add features you're missing? `*` Themes? Personal extensions?

Comment: @alexanoid Hi, note that I split my answer into three answers as requested, so you might want to change your accepted answer if it's one of the others that satisfied you more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) solution, which is the closest to what you're looking for:

### [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/pricing) for [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) or [Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise)

- It's StackOverflow, the closest you'll get to StackOverflow
- On premise

Comment: Please write one solution per answer, thanks :-)

Comment: OK :) So should I split it now? Does it matter which of them I leave in that answer and which I move to a new one?

Comment: Good question, we don't know which one the asker liked enough to accept the answer... that's why I prefer one solution per answer, to avoid having to try and guess what solution is relevant. Just choose the one you prefer :-)

Comment: So if the OP won't respond about it - I'll just know it for the future!

Comment: Also, please move your "Notes" section as comments to the question, thanks!

Comment: Done, I moved it to be a comment on the question :) Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Would you mind splitting the solutions into different answers?

Comment: Done! Each relevant suggestion was moved to a separate answer. I left the StackOverflow for Teams/Enterprise here since I think it best fits to what the OP was looking for

Answer (score 1):

We used [OSQA](https://github.com/dzone/osqa) at the last agency I worked at (3 years ago).  OSQA is a 'community version' of the 'enterprise' [AnswerHub](http://community.dzonesoftware.com/index.html).

At the time, it seemed to work okay - definitely not as slick as Stack Overflow, but still worthwhile (q&a, comments, tags, votes, badges).   Ultimately the culture of of contributing to Q&A didn't take off in company, but I participated for a while, and it was fit for purpose.

Looking at it now, it seems that the open source version gets very little love: it's still running Django 1.6(!!) and numerous PRs are pending (including an upgrade to Django 1.8 a year ago).

If you're a python person, then I'd recommend checking out the [network graph](https://github.com/dzone/osqa/network) / PRs.  The basics are there, if you're looking for a 'fixer-upper'.

Answer (score 1):

**[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io)** is open source Question-&-Answers software. It's a cross between StackOverflow and novel forum software like Discourse and Flarum.

In addition to Q&A topics, there are *Idea* type topics — if your colleagues / customers / users have ideas about how to improve things, and would like to post feedback and discuss. There're open-ended discussions, e.g. for talking about news and blog posts.

Talkyard is open source, [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard), I'm developing it. There's optional SaaS hosting.

Below is a sample discussion, actually copied from [this StackOverflow question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/2): (CC-By-SA)

[image: A question and answers about how to wake up on time]



<sub>(StackOverflow has deleted the question shown above, and the related community, so the link to the question over at `productivity.stackexchange.com` is dead.)</sub>

Comment: thanks for your answer. Talkyard looks really great! Is it possible to integrate Talkyard with the existing authentication on the site with no needs to register twice(once on my website and also in Talkyard)?

Comment: @alexanoid That sounds like Signe Sign-On? Yes there's SSO via an API; here's a topic about that: https://www.talkyard.io/-121/single-sign-on-and-api. SSO reportedly works fine, still it's fairly new, not that thoroughly tested yet. — Hmm the topic I linked is a bit long and complicated to read, maybe I could write some better looking docs about SSO (what do you think?)

Answer (score 0):

### [Question2Answer](https://github.com/q2a/question2answer)

- Open source
- Written in PHP
- Flexible and customizable
- Support for plugins, authentication, badges etc.
- I used it in a closed organization a few years ago and was pretty satisfied. I made some changes and added functionality, it was nice.

  - Customized the authentication to use [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) and [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))
  - Added support for RTL
  - Modified the theme

Answer (score 0):

### [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org)

- Open source
- Available also as a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) solution
- Written in Ruby
- Flexible and customizable
- Support for plugins, authentication, badges etc.
- One of the creators is Jeff Atwood, a co-founder of StackOverflow
- It's basically for discussions, but it can be used greatly also for Q&A, read a bit about it. I really liked it, but haven't used it myself because when I was looking for a Q&A platform it was just released as beta and wasn't production ready (a few years ago).
- [Tons of features](https://www.discourse.org/features)